# Removing the timestamp from a date in an Excel pivot table connected to a cube

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, ssas

So I have a cube created in Analysis Services 2008 R2. The cube has some dates on one of the non time dimensions. When I put the date on the filters in the excel pivot table, it always puts the date as, for example, 01/18/2012 00:00:00.000. Is it possible to exclude the timestamp from it? I tried using the format cell in excel, but it does nothing to it. I also tried converting from the source (The source is a view from a SQL Server database) from datetime to date using Convert(date,fieldWithDateInfo), and that drops the timestamp, but then Excel treats the field as string, and then the filters start acting really funky. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

check the "format string" property for the attribute...I believe the "shortdate" option is what you want.

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me - but my properties box didn't look the same either, so I may have a different version. I could not find FormatString in the Basic category, only a Format under Source in Key Columns. Are you sure that screenshot is SSAS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Add a calculated column to your time dimension using the code below

```
CONVERT(Varchar, [YOUR DATE COLUMN], 103) AS Date_UK
```

and change the 'Name Column' attribute to your new calculated column for the datetime dimension attribute